# Trouble converting CSV date from non standard format SQL

Tags: sql, type-conversion, sql-insert, sql-server-2016, sqldatatypes

I have dates in the format **01jan2020** (without a space or any separator) and need to convert this to a date type in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

The data was loaded from a `.CSV` file into a table (call it `TestData`, column is `Fill_Date`).

To join on a separate table to pull back data for another process, I need the `TestData` column `Fill_Date` to be in the correct format (`MM-DD-YYYY`) for my query to run correctly.

`Fill_Date` is currently in table `TestData` as datatype `varchar(50)`.

I want to either see if it is possible to convert it with `TestData` table or directly insert the result into a 2nd table that is formatted.

Thanks (NEWB)

Comment: The correct format is YYYY-MM-DD.  That is the ISO standard format for dates and recognized by most databases.  Converting a string to a date is highly database-dependent, so you need to tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: try `select convert(date,'01JAN2021',106)`

Comment: You should **NOT** store dates as strings!  Sooner rather than later, this will come around to bite you and cause trouble and heartache. Use the **most approprirate** datatypes - always - here, it's a `DATE` if you don't need time, or `DATETIME2(n)` if you do need time

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving by converting the data while dropping into a temp table, deleting old value, and then inserting from that table back into the *TestData* table.

`CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(date,[fill_date]),101) AS fill_date`